# Apply function to each pixel of the image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Is there a method in OpenCV which takes an input matrix, an output matrix and a function, and applies this function to each pixel? E.g a function like "check value of pixel, if it's below a certain threshold, set it to 0, otherwise keep the value"

I know I can iterate myself over the pixels of a matrix and apply the function myself, just wondering if there is a function which would save me this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If performance is a concern, the following links might be of interest to you:

- [How to scan images](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html)
- [Documentation of the LUT function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#lut)

You can easily create an appropriate LUT if you work with gray scale images.

Comment: LUT seems good, sadly it says it takes only 8-bit matrices. Is there one with 16-bit?

Comment: There is no predefined version for 16-bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply lambda function like this (assume for a gray-scale image):

```
std::for_each(mat.begin<uchar>(), mat.end<uchar>()
              , [](uchar& pixel) {  
                     /* do something with pixel */ 
                });
```

But still, it's actually a loop.

---

**Edit:** You can use [`remap`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=remap#remap) if you want to apply a generic geometrical transformation to an image.

Comment: performance-wise, how good is this solution compared to iterating through with pointer-manipulation?

Comment: @BananaCode I am afraid there will be no big difference here.

Comment: I get an error when I execute this code. Not sure if I'm missing something. error: expected expression
std::for_each(test.begin<uchar>(), test.end<uchar>(), [](uchar& pixel) {
                                                      ^

Comment: Useful information: if the image dtype is unsigned use `uchar`, otherwise use `float` if real-valued. In the lambda function, modify pixel in-place; no need to return anything.