# How to quickly access pixel colors of each frame using CvCameraViewListener

Tags: java, android, opencv, camera, pixel

I want to write a simple Android OpenCV application which takes each camera frame and does some calculations on the pixels of the frame. I'm using the below code. The problem is that its dead slow.

```
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        for(int u = 0; u < frame_width; u++) {
        for (int v = 0; v < frame_height; v++) {
            double[] current_color = mRgba.get(v, u);
            current_color[0] = current_color[0]/2;
            mRgba.put(v,u, current_color);
        }
    }
    return mRgba;
```

Alternatively, if I use the below code, it runs very smoothly.

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
Mat imgCanny = new Mat(height,width,CvType.CV_8UC1);
Imgproc.Canny(mRgba,imgCanny,50,150);
return imgCanny;
}
```

So I assume that the slowness is caused by accessing each individual pixel. That's 1024*768 pixels in my phone. Unfortunately, I need to access each individual pixel for my logic to work. Is there a faster way to access and modify each pixel?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329318/apply-function-to-each-pixel-of-the-image

Answer (score 1):

1) You are iterating over the columns of the image. Your images are large enough that this will be very slow due to cache misses. Every two consecutive pixels in a column are actually scanWidth pixels away from each other in memory.  *Instead iterate over the rows*  by swapping the order of your loops. Start with this optimization and you might be surprised how much faster it is.

2) *Don't use `mRgba.get(u,v)` in a loop*.  I don't use openCV in Java, but in C++ I would get a pointer to the start of each row and operate on the pixels sequentially in each row. In Java you can create a `double[]` buffer the size of the row and use the `int   get(int row, int col, double[] data)` to get the entire row of data at a time. Similarly for the `put` function. I don't know how to access the underlying data buffer in Java (ie: without copying). If you know how to do this, let me know.

3) After you've done 1 and 2, if you want to make it even faster and you have access to multiple cores, you could *perform your row operations in parallel*. I can't advise you on how to do this in Java, but maybe someone else can or you can check out the documentation.

I'd be interested in your results, so report back if you can. Thanks.